# Wrong output: Some test cases are failing while other test cases are passing

Tags: python, python-3.x

Wrote a program to determine the minimum number of jumps it will take Emma to jump from her starting position to the last cloud.

Here's the full question: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/jumping-on-the-clouds/problem

Certain test cases are failing.

Example 1:

Input: 1. 50

2. 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0

Expected Output: 28

Example 2:

Input: 1. 100

2. 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0

Expected Output: 53

Example 3:

Input: 1. 100.

2. 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0

Expected Output: 54

Example 4:

1. 85
2. 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0

Expected Output: 46

THE ABOVE 4 TEST CASES ARE FAILING FOR THE PROGRAM GIVEN BELOW.

What is the problem with the code written below that it's not giving the desired output?

```
def jumpingOnClouds(c):
    moves = 0
    i=0
    while i < len(c)-1:
        if c[i] == 0:
            try:
                if c[i]==c[i+2]:
                    moves+=1
                    i+=2
            except:
                pass
            try:
                if c[i]==c[i+1]:
                    moves+=1
                    i+=1
            except:
                pass

    return moves
```

Comment: Your code fails on `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not incrementing the index if you get an exception. So it may be stuck in infinite loop if the input is like this: [0 1 0 0]. First you start at 0. Then you go to index 2. In the next iteration you will be accessing a[4] which is out of bounds. You will catch the exception. But the program is stuck in infinite loop and it will never end since you have not incremented the index.

Here is an improved version of your method:

```
def min_moves(a, n):
    i = 0
    moves = 0
    while i < n-1:
        if i+2 < n and a[i+2] == 0:
            i += 2
            moves += 1
            continue

        if i+1 < n and a[i+1] == 0:
            i += 1
            moves += 1
            continue

    return moves
```

Comment: For the first example, I'm actually getting an output. But while the expected output is 28, the output I get is 32.

Comment: Just some small improvement to your method. Your method doesn't go till the last element of the array.

Comment: @AnishNarayan Can you cite an example input where my code will fail?

Comment: The variable 'i' doesn't get incremented when both the 'if' conditions fail. Only then we can go to the next element in the array. Also the 'if' condition should check whether both a[i] and a[i+2] are equal (or a[i+1] and a[i] are equal in case of second 'if' condition).  And while i < n-1 goes only until the second last element of the array whereas while i < n goes till last element of the array. The code I suggested includes all these.

Comment: The question says, it's always possible to win the game. So a case where both if cases fail will not occur. Also, I have submitted my code and it passes all TC's.